# Boundary of a bounded set is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

I was wondering if my proof is not wrong. I'd appreciate if it could be reviewed.

Prove: the boundary of a bounded set is compact.

> **Proof:**
>
> Suppose $U$ is a bounded set. We know that $\overline{U}=U^{\circ} \cup \partial U$, that is, the closure of $U$ is the union of the interior of $U$ and the boundary of $U$. Moreover, $\overline{U}$ is compact by Heine-Borel. Thus there exists open cover of $\overline{U}$, which is $\{X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$. There also exists a finite subcover of $\overline{U}$, which is $\{X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A_0}$, where $A_0 \subset A$. But $\partial U \subset \overline{U}$, so $\{X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A_0}$ is also an open cover for $\partial U$, and so $\{X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A_0}$ is a finite subcover of $\partial U$. Hence, $\partial U$ is compact.

Comment: Nit pick.  Is your metric space complete?

Comment: Same mistake as in the other thread. You start with an open cover of a set which is not the one you want to prove being compact. In addition, since you know Heine-Borel already, you can use it. But, of course, you can also deal with open coverings. It's your choice.

Comment: you can't invoke Heine--Borel unless your space is $R^n$ which you haven't said. Your result is not tree without some restrictions on the space such as being $R^n.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof isn't quite right at the moment, because you have to consider any open cover of $\partial U$, which may or may not be an open cover of $\overline{U}$.

However, there's an easy way to fix this: given an open cover $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $\partial U$, add $U^o$ to the cover to obtain an open cover of $\overline{U}$, then argue as in your original proof.

Comment: Why would it be needed to obtain an open cover of $\overline{U}$ if what has to be proved is that $\partial U$ is compact, not $\overline U$?

Comment: Well, the idea is to use the compactness of $\overline{U}$ to show that the open cover has a finite subcover. By the way, as the comments pointed out, if we're in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then it would be faster to just invoke the Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: I don't understand why can't we just say that since $\partial U$ is bounded, it has an open cover, and thus it has a finite subcover? Why do we need to bother about $\overline{U}$? We're in a general topological space. @carmichael561

Comment: I think you're mixing up the quantifiers in the definition of compactness. You must show that every open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: If we know that $\partial U$ is a closed and bounded set (since $U$ is finite), then the topological space of which $U$ is a subset can be an open cover of $\partial U$. But any open cover has a finite subcover, correct? I think I'm completely lost.

Comment: So I said that if $K$ is a set, there's an open cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ of $\partial K$. Since $\partial K$ is bounded, there exists a finite subcover $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A_0}$ of $\partial K$. Now consider $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A_0} U_\alpha\cup K^\circ$, which is a finite subcover of $\overline{K}$. Thus $\overline{K}$ is compact. But $\partial K \subset \overline{K}$, thus $\partial K$ is compact.